# How can I dinamically map a value in a JSON that depends upon another value in the same JSON with AlamoFireObjectMapper?

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire, objectmapper

TL;DR I want to model the field `attributes` (an object) present inside each element of an array, according to the value of the field `type` present in the same element.

Imagine the following scenario: I have an endpoint that will give me information about animals. There are different animals, each with different attributes (we might assume a superclass, but it doesn't make sense to have a single class with all the attributes together)

```
[
    {
        "name": "Lassie",
        "type": "DOG",
        "attributes": {
            "hairColor": "gold",
            "jumpHeight": "2 mts"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Rex",
        "type": "DINOSAUR",
        "attributes": {
            "isCarnivore": "true",
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Nemo",
        "type": "FISH",
        "attributes": {
            "avgSwimSpeed": "10 km/h",
            "hasInjuredFin": "false"
        }
    }
]
```

I'm using AlamofireObjectMapper to map the JSON to my models, but what I want to model is different classes for the attributes (DogAttributes, FishAttributes and so on), that I could generically manage with a protocol or a superclass.

The problem is that I don't know how to tell the mapper that **according to the value of the attribute "type"**, when the object "attributes" is generated from the JSON, I don't want it to be the superclass, but a specific concrete class.

So, how do I tell the mapper that `if type == "DOG"` the attributes objects has to be an instance of DogAttributes?

Answer (score 2):

As you mention, the attributes objects don't seem to have any overlap, so making them all a subclass or conform to a protocol doesn't make much sense unless you aren't sharing the entirety of the code.

In the abstract, you could do a custom transform https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper#custom-transforms.  In the custom transform, you describe how to convert from JSON to an Object and back.

```
class Animal: StaticMappable {
    var name:String
    var type:String
    var attributes:Atttributes

    public override func mapping(map: Map) {
        super.mapping(map: map)
        name           <-  map["name"]
        type           <-  map["type"]
        if type == "DOG" {
            attributes     <-  (map["attributes"], DogTransfrom())
        } else if type == "DINOSAUR" {
            attributes     <-  (map["attributes"], DinoTransfrom())
        }
    }
}


protocol Attributes { }
struct DogAttributes: Attributes { }
struct DinosaurAttributes: Attributes { }
```

---

**EDIT**

If you want to parse each object differently, then rather than calling `Mapper<Animal>.mapArray(JSONString:string)`, you would need to loop through the json array and pass different mapping classes.

If you had

```
class Animal: StaticMappable {}
class Dog: Animal {}
class Dinosaur: Animal{}
```

and your parsing method (psuedo code)

```
func parseJSON(json:JSON) -> [Animal] {
   var animals = [Animal]()
   for animal in json['animals'] {
      if animal['type'].lowercased() == 'dog' {
          let dog = Mapper<Dog>().map(JSONObject: animal.dictionaryObject)
          animals.append(dog)
      } else if animal['type'].lowercased() == 'dinosaur' {
          let dino = Mapper<Dinosaur>().map(JSONObject: animal.dictionaryObject)
          animals.append(dino)
      }
   }
   return animals
}
```

Comment: So, I should basically define a Transformation for each class, right? Do you know how I could apply this if I needed the whole class to be polymorphic instead of just the attributes var?